# Displaying selected lines using head and tail command

Tags: bash, unix, command-line

How can I use the ‘head’ and ‘tail’ commands with piping to display only lines 2 and 3 from my selected file 'imaginaryfile' (which has 10 lines)?

What I've tried so far:

```
>$ head -n  3 imaginaryfile | tail -n 2 > > (head -n 1) > > (tail -n 1)
```

The output for line 3 comes, but I didn't get an output of line 2. What can I do to correct this and get an output of line 2 and line3?

Comment: I'd just use a single `sed` invocation: `sed -n '2,3p; 3q' imaginaryfile`

Comment: It would be helpful for future readers to see the testfile contents in the question and the desired output. To get lines 2 and three from a 10 line testfile using tail and head, you can just ```tail -n +2 testfile | head -n2```

Answer (score 3):

```
head -3 file | tail -n +2
```

`head` will print the first 3 lines. This output will be the input for the `tail` command which will start printing from the second line to the end.

From `man tail`

> -n, --lines=[+]NUM
> output the last NUM lines, instead of the last 10; or use -n +NUM  to  output  starting  with
> line NUM

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in simple `awk`.

```
awk '
FNR>=2 && FNR<=3{
  print
  if(FNR==3){
    exit
  }
}
' Input_file
```

---

---

Giving ranges in variable in `awk` from where to where you want to print.

```
awk -v from="2" -v till="3" '
FNR>=from && FNR<=till{
  print
  if(FNR==till){
    exit
  }
}
' Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

For printing selected lines, use any of these Perl one-liners:

```
# Explicit and simple code:
perl -ne 'print if $. >= 2 && $. <= 3' input_file

# Shorter, but less explicit code:
perl -ne 'print if 2..3' input_file

# Longer and more complex code, but runs faster for larger files, 
# because the script exits after line 3:
perl -ne 'next if $. < 2; last if $. > 3; print;' input_file
```

Example:

```
seq 1 10 | perl -ne 'print if $. >= 2 && $. <= 3'
2
3
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.

`$.` : current input line number.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlvar`: Perl predefined variables](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)